# Does a resident (Non owner/renter) of a condo have any responsibility for damages done to another unit? (US/Florida)

Tags: united-states, liability, insurance, florida, condominium

Situation: I live with my mother in a condo.  The condo is 100% in her name,  the only legal relationship I have with the property is that it is my official residence.  A water leak caused damage to the downstairs neighbor's ceiling.  The subrogation company for the neighbor's home owner insurance keeps trying to collect from me.   I am 99% certain that all legal liability in this case should go to my mother, which I have told them.    Is there any way in which a pure resident could be held at all liable in a case like this?  (Take this as a hypothetical, I'm not looking for official legal advice.)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

If the resident’s negligence caused the damage. For example, if the resident ran a bath, forgot, and the overflowing water caused damage, the damaged party could sue the resident.

Comment: How would the damaged party know who caused the flood?  How I imagined it would be the damaged party would sue the owner of the unit, and then the owner could sue the resident in turn?

Comment: @Alan who cares how they know - there are many ways they could

Comment: How would they know: They might for example call the owner, who truthfully answers that there is no damage in the flat that caused the flood, so it must have been the occupier who ran a bath.